# XML string from xml-seq

Tags: xml-parsing, clojure

I have a xml-seq:

```
({:tag :foo, :attrs nil, :content nil})
```

And I need to parse it to a xml string to store in my memory like this:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<foo></foo>"
```

Already tried clojure.data.xml/emit-str but without success, any tips?

Comment: How you are calling emit-str ?

Comment: (clojure.data.xml/emit-str(xml-seq (clojure.xml/parse(java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.(.getBytes (str "<foo></foo>")))))) gives the following error IllegalArgumentException No implementation of method: :gen-event of protocol: #'clojure.data.xml/EventGeneration found for class: clojure.lang.PersistentStructMap  clojure.core/-cache-protocol-fn (core_deftype.clj:541)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `clojure.xml/parse`, switch to `clojure.data.xml/parse` and your round-trip should work:

```
(clojure.data.xml/emit-str
  (xml-seq (clojure.data.xml/parse
             (java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.
               (.getBytes (str "<foo></foo>"))))))
; => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><foo></foo>"
```